# Could VsCode extension get any language server's completion items?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

As the title, I want to get typescript language server's completion items in my own extension. How should I do?

If there is another way except running the language server by myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `vscode.executeCompletionItemProvider` [built-in command](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands) for this:

```
const list = await vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeCompletionItemProvider',
    vscode.Uri.file('/path/to/file.ts'),
    new vscode.Position(line, character))
```

Similar commands exist for other functionality, such as listing references.

Comment: Thank you very much.  the command can get other suggestions, but executing the command in my IntelliSense extension causes a loop call. I didn't find a way to avoid this.

Comment: I use a `flag` to resolve this. Thank you very much to solve my problem.